# Video blocking Raspberry PI HDMI console

Tags: camera, hdmi

Trying to troubleshoot network failure of a Pi B, but when hooking up an HDMI monitor, only camera *video* is viewable.

Is there a way to configure the Pi to *NOT* throw video out HDMI? At least if a console were available it might be possible to isolate the network issue.

Comment: What OS are you running on the pi?

Comment: Running Jessie current

Answer (score 0):

Google [your question](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=7570) before you post

```
    /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o
```

Comment: Well, .. I never would have thought to Google for the wrong answer, .. but I will be happy to try it. Thanks!

Comment: As I thought, .. wrong answers don't solve the problem, just take time to test. tvservice turns of the HDMI **port**, .. does not disable the camera video.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out one way to avoid the problem, .. wrote a script to test the network and reboot if it's unreachable. Log the event and add any other data desired for troubleshooting.

Now, have to isolate the actual problem, but at least the hang can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The program or script that uses the camera activates video output via HDMI. To prevent this, you must either stop the program/script or change it to disable HDMI output. In case of picamera (Python API) you can comment out the call to the start_preview() method and the script should work normally otherwise.